# apt-get doesn't get latest kernel

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, kernel, updates

One day I noticed that I have installed on my system the linux-headers packages until version 3.13.0-92. On the contrary, linux-image packages are only installed until version 3.13.0-39.

`apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` did not installed nothing. To update my kernel, I had to do a manual `apt-get install` for 3.13.0-92 version of linux kernel image.

What happened and how can I fix it to avoid future problems? I have Lubuntu 14.04.

Comment: You have to use `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` for kernel upgrades.

Comment: I answered with that, but apparently not the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the meta package is not installed for some reason.

You need to install it by this command

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

For Lubuntu 14.04 it will point to the latest 3.13.0-x kernel and will always update it to the latest one.

Currently it is 3.13.0-93.

Comment: 3.19 was a typo.

Comment: Yes, it is not present. Probably it was uninstalled by accident by me or by automatic purge. I let you know if it will fixed the problem. Thank you.

Comment: It will fix it for sure.